# regex returns extra blank group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Can someone explain this behaviour (or what I'm doing wrong):

```
//matches twice (should only match once)
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=Start )(.*)(?= End)");
Match match = regex.Match("Start blah End");
Console.Out.WriteLine("Groups:" + match.Groups.Count + " " + match.Groups[0] + " " + match.Groups[0]);  //2 groups: "blah" and "blah"

//matches once, but blank result (should not match)
Match match2 = regex.Match("Shouldn't match at all");
Console.Out.WriteLine("Groups:" + match2.Groups.Count + " " + match2.Groups[0]);  //1 group: ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groups[0] is always returned, as it represents the entire expression.  In your case `match2.Groups[0].Success` returns false, since there is no match.  `match.Groups[0].Success` returns true, and `match.Groups[1]` has the matching group.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ***The GroupCollection object returned by the Match.Groups property
>   always has at least one member. If the regular expression engine
>   cannot find any matches in a particular input string, the
>   Group.Success property of the single Group object in the collection is
>   set to false and the Group object's Value property is set to
>   String.Empty.*** If the regular expression engine can find a match, the
>   first element of the GroupCollection object returned by the Groups
>   property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression
>   pattern. Each subsequent element represents a captured group, if the
>   regular expression includes capturing groups. For more information,
>   see the "Grouping Constructs and Regular Expression Objects" section
>   of the Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions article.